# Can you attack yourself?

Tags: stratego

Seems like there would never be any reason to attack yourself in Stratego.. unless you do screw up the placement of your pieces like a noob. So I ask, can you attack yourself? Of course, it doesn't say so in the rules, probably because they hope no one is stupid enough to need to. I'd like an answer with some kind of reference or "proof".

Comment: There's an old Doctor Who adventure where a chess game is resolved by the white and black pawns teaming up to take on the king.  I love the idea of a Stratego puzzle that can only be solved by attacking one's own pieces :)

Comment: I had never considered Stratego puzzles (in the same vein, presumably, as chess puzzles) before. They seem like they'd be really fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.** From p. 4 of [these rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Stratego.PDF):

> [Pieces] cannot move into a onto a square occupied by another piece (unless attacking).

And from p. 5

> To attack on your turn, take your attacking piece and lightly tap **your opponent's** piece.

You can only attack your opponent's pieces, and your own pieces cannot share a square in any way.

Comment: I saw that 2nd quote in the rules, but it didn't seem to direct. I guess it's the closest to answer out there. Thanks man.